# How to use command lines an activate theme in wp - cli also setup Vagrant/Sage Theme?

Tags: themes, wp-cli

I'm still a beginner using Command lines and [Sage Wordpress Starter Theme](https://github.com/roots/sage#install-dependencies) Write steps on what I did to setup everything on my iMac . If you need how wp-cli works and Sage Wordpress Starter works please help me.

First Step: I have setup my VVV server and did the vagrant ssh. After I did vagrant ssh I create a new theme based on Sage by using Composer (composer create-project roots/sage web/app/themes/your-theme-name 9.0.0-alpha.1).

Second Step: I got confuse on try to understand how to add a new theme inside my Wordpress-Develop folder and they make it activate by using wp-cli.

Three Step: Install dependencies I can do myself just need help with this second step.

```
$ wp theme activate your-theme-name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A theme slug, the path to a local zip file, or URL to a remote zip file.
- If set, get that particular version from wordpress.org, instead of the stable version.
- If set, the command will overwrite any installed version of the theme, without prompting for confirmation.
- If set, the theme will be activated immediately after install.

## Install the latest version from wordpress.org and activate

```
$ wp theme install twentysixteen --activate
Installing Twenty Sixteen (1.2)
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentysixteen.1.2.zip...
Unpacking the package...
Installing the theme...
Theme installed successfully.
Activating 'twentysixteen'...
Success: Switched to 'Twenty Sixteen' theme.
```

## Install from a local zip file

```
$ wp theme install ../my-theme.zip
```

## Install from a remote zip file

```
$ wp theme install http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/my-theme.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=123&amp;Expires=456&amp;Signature=abcdef
```

Comment: But do I have to be inside the WordPress fold to do this and if you I have a google hangout so I explain my problem or skype.

Comment: you must have on root path